# How Do I Manipulate Calculated David's Scores for Individuals Across 10 Groups to Use In a GLMM in R?

Tags: r, hierarchy

I am trying to create a mixed linear effects model in R to explore how personality affects dominance.

I have 10 groups of 12 individuals, either male-biased (9/3), female-biased (3/9), or even (6/6), and have calculated David's Scores of Dominance. I have also calculated Normalised David's Scores for individuals in each group.

Boldness scores for each individual will be my independent variable.

Davids scores are supposed to be my dependent variable.

Individual and group will be my random effects (I think).

However, I am really stuck as to how I'm supposed to use the 20 sets of David's scores (one for each gender in each group) in the linear mixed model!

Some individuals are present in more than one of the 10 groups, so this has confused me as well.

I know that I need to do one model for males, and one model for females.

Any help as to how I should manipulate this data so that I can use it in the model would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like more of a methods question. CV.com is the place for those.

Comment: CV.com isn't a website?

Comment: Short for CrossValidated.com in the same manner as SO is short for StackOverflow. Formally `https://stats.stackexchange.com`